# Projected Shadow with shadow matrix, simple test fails

Tags: opengl, matrix, shadow

I wrote a little program to test how projected shadows work.

I wanted to check in particular the case where the point to project (it could be the vertex of a triangle) is not situated between the light source and the plane but behind the light itself, that is the light is between the point and the plane.

The problem is that my little program is not even working in the case where the point is between the light and plane. I checked the calculations tens of times, so I guess the error should be logic, but I cant find it..

Here the code

```
public class test {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 2;
    int w = 3;
    float floor[][] = {
        {-100.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f},
        {100.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f},
        {100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f},
        {-100.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f}};
    private float shadow_floor[] = new float[16];
    float light_position[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 1.0f};

    public test() {
        //Find floorplane based on thre known points
        float plane_floor[] = calculatePlane(floor[1], floor[2], floor[3]);

        //store shadowMatrix for floor
        shadow_floor = shadowMatrix(plane_floor, light_position);

        float[] point = new float[]{1.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f};

        float[] projectedPoint = pointFmatrixF(point, shadow_floor);

        System.out.println("point: (" + point[x] + ", " + point[y] + ", " + point[z] + ", "
                + point[w] + ")");
        System.out.println("projectedPoint: (" + projectedPoint[x] + ", " + projectedPoint[y]
                + ", " + projectedPoint[z] + ", " + projectedPoint[w] + ")");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test test = new test();
    }

    // make shadow matrix
    public float[] shadowMatrix(float plane[], float light_pos[]) {
        float shadow_mat[] = new float[16];
        float dot;


        dot = plane[x] * light_pos[x] + plane[y] * light_pos[y]
                + plane[z] * light_pos[z] + plane[w] * light_pos[w];

        shadow_mat[0] = dot - light_pos[x] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[4] = -light_pos[x] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[8] = -light_pos[x] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[12] = -light_pos[x] * plane[3];

        shadow_mat[1] = -light_pos[y] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[5] = dot - light_pos[y] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[9] = -light_pos[y] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[13] = -light_pos[y] * plane[w];

        shadow_mat[2] = -light_pos[z] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[6] = -light_pos[z] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[10] = dot - light_pos[z] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[14] = -light_pos[z] * plane[w];

        shadow_mat[3] = -light_pos[w] * plane[x];
        shadow_mat[7] = -light_pos[w] * plane[y];
        shadow_mat[11] = -light_pos[w] * plane[z];
        shadow_mat[15] = dot - light_pos[w] * plane[w];

        return shadow_mat;
    }

    public float[] calculatePlane(float p1[], float p2[], float p3[]) {
        //Array for planlikningen
        float plane[] = new float[4];

        //Gitt to vektorer (tre punkter) i planet kan normalen regnes ut
        //Vi vil ha aboluttverdier
        plane[x] = Math.abs(((p2[y] - p1[y]) * (p3[z] - p1[z])) - ((p2[z] - p1[z])
                * (p3[y] - p1[y])));
        plane[y] = Math.abs(((p2[z] - p1[z]) * (p3[x] - p1[x])) - ((p2[x] - p1[x])
                * (p3[z] - p1[z])));
        plane[z] = Math.abs(((p2[x] - p1[x]) * (p3[y] - p1[y])) - ((p2[y] - p1[y]) 
                * (p3[x] - p1[x])));
        plane[w] = -(plane[x] * p1[x] + plane[y] * p1[y] + plane[z] * p1[z]);


        return plane;
    }

    public float[] pointFmatrixF(float[] point, float[] matrix) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 1;
        int z = 2;
        float[] transformedPoint = new float[4];

        transformedPoint[x] =
                matrix[0] * point[x]
                + matrix[4] * point[y]
                + matrix[8] * point[z]
                + matrix[12];
        transformedPoint[y] =
                matrix[1] * point[x]
                + matrix[5] * point[y]
                + matrix[9] * point[z]
                + matrix[13];
        transformedPoint[z] =
                matrix[2] * point[x]
                + matrix[6] * point[y]
                + matrix[10] * point[z]
                + matrix[14];
        transformedPoint[w] = 1;

        return transformedPoint;
    }
}
```

If the plane is an xy plane, the light is on (0, 0, 10) and the point on (1, 0, 5) then the projected point on the plane should be (2, 0, 0), but the program is returning (400000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

Comment: I'd work through the example on paper, using the same steps your program takes, then check your program against what you had to do to get the math to work. ... It can even help just to carefully copy the program onto paper. I find it easier to erase and change things when it's handwritten than on a printout.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work, I was getting always the same error, the error was logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I was assuming incorrectly that the last coordinate of the projected point was 1, but it wasn't.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320527/projecting-a-point-on-a-plane-through-a-matrix