# Projection of rotation matrix

Tags: opengl, rotation

I have a rotation matrix I use to show a 3D-vector with openGL. Now I would like to have a projection of this vector on the XY-plane. So I´m looking for the rotation matrix that I can use to do this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be rotation matrix, but general 4x4 transformation matrix for doing a projection on a plane. It is often used to do a "shadow" matrix for flattening objects onto a floor.

See more here: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/StencilTalk/tsld021.htm

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320527/projecting-a-point-on-a-plane-through-a-matrix

[Projected Shadow with shadow matrix, simple test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197903/projected-shadow-with-shadow-matrix-simple-test-fails)